# Obtaining element position relative to the nth parent

Tags: jquery, position, offset

I am building a dynamic image scroller and I need to know how to call the offset position of an element relative to its nth parent.

Any ideas?

Comment: Get the absolute offsets of the two elements, then work out the difference?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getRelativePosition( element, nthparent_of_element ){
   var posParent = $(nthparent_of_element).position();
   var posElement = $(element).position();
   return { top: posElement.top - posParent.top, 
            left: posElement.left - posParent.left};
}
```